# Create a monthly trend line chart with the count of a value as y variable

Tags: r

I have the dataframe below :

```
name<-c("John","John","John","John2","John2","John2")
Dealer<-c("ASD","ASD","ASD","ASDG","ASDF","ASD")
Date<-c("2020-01-03","2020-01-04","2020-01-05","2020-02-03","2020-02-04","2020-02-05")
dataset<-data.frame(name,Dealer,Date)
```

and I want a monthly trend visualization of the count of `name` , filterable by `Dealer`.

I have reached to the code below but I do not know how to find the count of each `name`. I feel that I have to convert my dataframe somehow.

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(dataset, aes(x = Date, y = , color = Dealer)) +
  geom_line() +
  scale_x_date(date_breaks = "1 months", date_labels = "%b '%y") +
  theme_minimal()
```

*edited dataframe with a dataset with all values being the same in `name` and `Dealer`

```
name<-c("John","John","John","John","John","John","John")
Dealer<-c("ASD","ASD","ASD","ASD","ASD","ASD","ASD")
Date<-c("2020-01-03","2020-01-04","2020-01-05","2020-01-06","2020-01-07","2020-01-08","2020-01-09")
dataset<-data.frame(name,Dealer,Date)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
library(tidyverse); library(lubridate)
dataset %>%
  # Convert "Date" into date form
  mutate(Date = ymd(Date)) %>%
  # Count how many occasions of each name-Dealer-month combo
  count(name, Dealer, month = floor_date(Date, "month")) %>%
  # Add rows for missing months for each existing name-Dealer combo
  complete(month, nesting(name, Dealer), fill = list(n = 0)) %>%

  ggplot(aes(month, n, color = name)) +
  geom_line() +
  scale_x_date(date_breaks = "1 months", date_labels = "%b\n'%y") +
  theme_minimal() +
  facet_wrap(~Dealer)
```

[image]

Comment: I liked you solutionthat works but for some reason when all the values are the same (name ,Dealer) then I get no lines plus count with decimals in the y axis. CHECK THE EDIT

Comment: If you only have one month, then geom_line won't show anything and isn't an appropriate geom. You might add a `geom_point` layer if that's a situation you're going to encounter.

Comment: no i will have many months, so your suggestion is point..hmm ok but what about the decimals?